# How to perform get operation on my url to obtain data, using aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have an URL, I want to get data in that URL to AWS, so that I can store it in AWS Dynamo-db. For example I got that data in postman using get operation. but, in AWS i don't have any clue how to perform get operation to perform the get operation so that i can store that data in AWS. any suggestions ??

Answer (score -1):

The best, easiest and quickest way to do it is use an AWS Lambda code which gets triggered when you receive a get request from an api gateway endpoint. This lambda code (in Python programming language) will use boto3 sdk to save data in dynamo DB table.

For starting point you can read this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html